# Running single karma test in PhpStorm/WebStorm

Tags: phpstorm, karma-runner, webstorm

I'm using PhpStorm and want to run karma tests for my *.ts

Here is my `karma.config.js`

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon Jan 16 2017 13:32:24 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon', 'fixture'],
        files: [
            'spec/**/*.spec.ts',
            'spec/fixtures/**/*.html',
        ],
        exclude: [],
        webpack: {
            module: webpackConfig.module,
            resolve: webpackConfig.resolve,
            plugins: [
                new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                    $: "jquery",
                    jQuery: "jquery",
                    "window.jQuery": "jquery",
                    Tether: 'tether',
                    "window.Tether": 'tether'
                })
            ],
        },
        preprocessors: {
            "spec/**/*.ts": ['webpack'],
            'spec/**/*.html': ['html2js'],
            'spec/**/*.json': ['json_fixtures']
        },
        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],//, 'Chrome'],
        singleRun: false,
        concurrency: Infinity
    })
};
```

I have Karma "Run/debug configuration" which is working fine - all tests are executed. But I want to run single test with right click on test (like in PHPUnit).

Screenshot:

[image]

But I have error:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong - how to use single test in PhpStorm?

Answer (score -2):

Solved:
I have to install `npm i --save-dev ts-node`